# How to clear browser back button history in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am designing a Web Application using `ReactJS`. In here, I am using `react-router-dom` for navigation purposes.

Here,it looks like

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
              <Route exact path='/login' element={<LoginPage />} />
              <Route exact path='/homePage' element={<HomePage />} />
              <Route exact path='/detailsPage' element={<DetailsPage />} />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Since `useHistory` is replaced by `useNavigation` in recent version, I am using  `useNavigation` for navigating  pages.

Code:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
const navigate = useNavigate();

 / **For Navigating ** /
navigate("/login")
```

It works great. But when I am naviagated to `loginPage`, I want to clear all the history stored in browser `Back` Button. I found Solutions in `useHistory`. But in `useNavigation`, its not working.

Code I tried:

```
navigate[0] = navigate[navigate.length - 1]
navigate("/login")
```

and this also

```
navigate("/login", { replace: true })
```

Its not working. I want to know how to clear all the history stored in `Browser Back Button` for my url. If i go back, i can even access homePage. I read their docs https://reach.tech/router/api/useNavigate
But can't find solutions. Please Help me with some solutions to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
navigate("/login", { replace: true })
```

i think this will working

Comment: I tried this. Its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the .replace method from react-router.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
const history = useHistory();
history.replace(`your page url`);
```

Comment: useHistory() is not available in react-router anymore. They changed to useNavigate()